# Python arguments and keyword-arguments best practices

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a Django App, where I am expecting to use many management.py commands.  I like the idea of python functions having parameters with default values, where you define the param as:

```
def function(param1=value1)
```

So I'm writing my management commands such that you input as follows:

```
python manage.py createdb user=some_user db_name=some_name
```

So far as I can tell, management.py commands don't accept this type of argument list, so I've created a helper to do the following:

```
def process_args(args=None):
    kwargs = {}
    if not args:
        return kwargs
    for i in args:
        try:
            k,v = i.split('=')
            kwargs[k] = v
        except ValueError, ve:
            raise CommandError("Please Enter All Arguments as key=value.  e.g. user=admin")
    return kwargs
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own, you could use typical parameter style, and use something like [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) to parse it:

```
python manage.py createdb --user=some_user --db_name=some_name
```

You'd just define your argument parser and then pass the `args` argument to its `parse_args()` method.

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work.  The BaseCommand class needs to have the options added to its option_list in order for it to recognize the option.  But according to the post below, using make_option has been deprecated.  Hence I'd like to use argparse, but how do I add the arguments to the BaseCommand class?

Comment: Honestly, I'd go with what @nrabinowitz suggested - use Django's built-in functionality when working with Django.

Answer (score 12):

**Updated:**
Per @rix, later versions of Django now use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html), which should be preferred.

**Original Answer:**

I believe the standard approach here is to use [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), which can hook into the existing option parsing Django uses already. The example [from the 1.6 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/):

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--delete',
            action='store_true',
            dest='delete',
            default=False,
            help='Delete poll instead of closing it'),
        )
    # ...
```

Now you have your command line arguments available in the `options` dictionary. The Python docs say `optparse` is deprecated, but I assume that the Django docs recommend it because it's what Django uses for its own management commands.

Comment: Really, you're going to give me -1 for citing the Django manual on a question about Django best practices, even though I noted that the Django recommendation was deprecated? Come on.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Don't recommend deprecated code.  It doesn't matter if django uses it or not.  [Related](http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2009/12/09/django-boss/)

Comment: In general, I would agree.  But the OP's question isn't about generic Python arg parsing, it's about the recommended way to do this *for Django management commands*. And there *is* a recommended way, using optparse, in the Django manual - recommended in part because that way you play well with Django's own parsing. It does matter whether Django uses it, if you're building code to work with Django.

Comment: +1 for being rational. it's all fine and good to be hard-line about not using deprecated code, but if your app has a dependency on a specific version of Django and a specific version of Python, it only makes sense to use the framework as it was designed. I'm sure a future Django version will switch over to argparse, and then we can all win our way back into @wim's good graces

Comment: I disagree with @wim regarding argparse in the Django context. If it was an answer, I was going to downvote it. Up to now, Django 1.7.4 is still using OptParse for their implementations in BaseCommand. Under normal conditions, I would prefer ArgParse and I used it many times, but seems that Django is still using OptParse, and so you should until they switch to ArgParse, or try package django-argparse-command==0.1.0.

Comment: In hindsight I actually disagree with my 2012 self now, too.  After having written a few management commands since, it became clear there is some functionality that you get through inheriting `BaseCommand` that you can't get easily by trying to avoid the deprecated module.  Practicality beats purity here.

Comment: It's kind of sad that django 1.7 is _still_ using deprecated code, when the superior `argparse` has been around for more than 5 years, but that is just a sign of what a big and slow moving beast django has unfortunately become.

Comment: As of 1.8 Django uses argparse.

Answer (score 3):

Docs over @ Python [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) are great, but for a quick copy paste answer to solve the original question (post Django 1.8) - here you go:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '-something',
            action='store',
            dest='something',
            default=None,
            help="something",
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print(options['something'])

python manage.py your_command -something='something'
```